# Крашится приложение Android

Tags: java, android

MainActivity:

```
private Button Num1, btn;
private EditText pass;


@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();

}


//  FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
// fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//    @Override
//  public void onClick(View view) {
//       Sandbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
//         .setAction("Action", null).show();


private void addListenerOnButton() {
    btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint
                        ("SetTextI18n")
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btn.setText("DONE");
                    btn.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
                    Toast.makeText(
                            MainActivity.this, pass.getText(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();
                }
            }
    );


    Num1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("MainActivity2");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });


}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void addListenerOnButton(View view) {
    btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint
                        ("SetTextI18n")
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btn.setText("DONE");
                    btn.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
                    Toast.makeText(
                            MainActivity.this, pass.getText(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();
                }
            }
    );
            Num1.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent("MainActivity2");
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });



}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.car">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="vk.com"
                    android:pathPattern="/vk.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Логи:

```
2019-04-04 19:21:17.327 5326-5326/com.example.car E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.car, PID: 5326
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.car/com.example.car.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.car.MainActivity.addListenerOnButton(MainActivity.java:44)
        at com.example.car.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

При запуске приложения на эмуляторе оно сразу-же закрывается "Car has stopped". Может ли это быть из-за неправильно выбранной версии Android? Возможно я что-то напутал с манифестом.

Сделал уже все что мог. Помогите, пожалуйста

Логи2:

```
2019-04-04 19:41:13.070 6101-6101/com.example.car E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.car, PID: 6101
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.car/com.example.car.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.car.MainActivity.addListenerOnButton(MainActivity.java:38)
        at com.example.car.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: Что по логам .?

Comment: Во-первых "крашится" не эмулятор и не студия, а только Ваше приложение. Во-вторых в студии есть `LogCat` - туда выводятся логи, в том числе ошибок . Содержимое логов может помочь выявить причину самостоятельно или с нашей помощью (если добавите в вопрос).

Comment: Вы не указали ресурсы кнопок: btn = findViewById(R.id. ид кнопки); в onCreate

Answer (score 5):

У Вас объявлены поля, но им не присвоено значений, далее идёт обращение к этим полям. Нужно в `onCreate` найти виджеты из разметки, чтобы с ними работать.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn.findViewById(R.id.yourButton); // здесь id кнопки
    // инициализация остальных вью
    // после можно устанавливать им слушателей, тексты, картинки и т.д.
    addListenerOnButton();
}
```

Comment: Все равно не помогло Логи новой ошибки в вопросе

Comment: Ну так а Вы не догадались заменить `yourButton` на id Вашей кнопки, объявленной в `activity_main.xml`. Или её вообще там нет? - тогда добавьте, студия конечно мощный инструмент, но читать мысли пока не умеет. И мы тоже, кстати - а макет Вы нам не показали.